# Accessing four extent values of layer using ArcObjects in C#?

Tags: arcobjects, layers, c#, extents

How can I access the four extent values of a layer shown in the below image using C# in ArcObjects?

[image]

Below is the code that i am using to achieve it but "AreaOfInterest" is null.

```
public ISpatialReference CreateSpatialRefGCS(ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.esriSRGeoCSType gcsType)
        {
            ISpatialReferenceFactory spatialRefFactory = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();
            IGeographicCoordinateSystem geoCS = spatialRefFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem((int)gcsType);
            return (ISpatialReference)geoCS;
        }

        public IEnvelope GetExtent(ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto.IFeatureLayer PolygonLayer)
        {
            try 
            {
                IEnvelope envelope = PolygonLayer.AreaOfInterest.Envelope;
                envelope.Project(CreateSpatialRefGCS(esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984));               
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return PolygonLayer.AreaOfInterest.Envelope;
        }
```

Comment: That's not a good way to create a WGS84 projection as ISpatialReference, try ISpatialReferenceFactory3 pSRf3 = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass(); ISpatialReference pDS_SR = pSRf3.CreateSpatialReference(4326); but you're not going to get those numbers from a geographic spatial reference; Geographic spatial references have the bounds -180,180 and -90,90. As for getting the extent try (PolygonLayer.FeatureClass as IGeoDataset).Extent http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000003m6000000

Comment: @MichaelStimson, (PolygonLayer.FeatureClass as IGeoDataset).Extent returns null.

Comment: Does the featureclass have any features in it?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this information from the source FeatureClass of the layer like so:

```
IFeatureClass source = (ILayer as IFeatureLayer).FeatureClass;
(source as IFeatureClassManage).UpdateExtent(); //per MichaelStimson's suggestion
IEnvelope extent = (source as IGeoDataset).Extent;
```

Comment: Yup, that's what I said, however this according to jay returns Null.. perhaps it would be a good idea to include a line with IFeatureClassManage.UpdateExtent http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002s2000000 first.. if the result is still Null there's likely to be a bigger problem; what feature storage type is the polygon layer jay? Is it shapefile, geodatabase, sde, KML, GML etc.? To implement IFeatureClass the data storage should implement IGeoDataset fully but if one or more geometries are broken that could confuse the extent.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, the feature type is "Simple" and geometry type is "Polygon"

Comment: @jay have you tried running the Repair Geometry geoprocessing tool in ArcMap on your layer? Also could you specify how you are retrieving the ILayer object before you pass it into your GetExtent method?

Comment: I did a quick test with 10.4.1 ... I got the extent from layer's featureclass using `IGeoDataset.Extent.Envelope`, doubled it with `IEnvelope.Expand`, then set `ILayer2.AreaOfInterest` to the expanded envelope.  I saved it to a lyr file, closed and reopened arcmap, then added the lyr file to an empty document.  It zoomed to the `ILayer2.AreaOfInterest` automatically.  When I right click and choose "Zoom to layer" it zoomed to the `featureclass`'s `IGeoDataset.Extent` - not to the `AreaOfInterest`.

Comment: I didn't check to confirm that `IGeoDataset.Extent` for the `FeatureLayer` returns the same thing as `IGeoDataset.Extent` for the `Featureclass`.